# Role of interfaces in nestjs framework

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I am trying to understand the role of interfaces in javascript nestjs framework. I understand that in general in programming we should always be programming to interfaces not classes. It helps with dependency injection and testing. I am trying to figure out if it is relevant in web development specifcally serverless programming.

Would someone be kind enough to provide some real world use cases for interfaces in nestjs?

Thanks,
Sridhar.

Comment: The question is too broad. It seems that you refer to DI and not interfaces in general, don't you? You may want to check https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-pattern and https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection which Nest heavily borrows from.

Comment: Hi, I am referring to interfaces in typescript and nestjs framework. I mentioned DI because that is one common use case of interfaces.

Comment: It's unclear if you refer to interfaces or types in general. Besides DI which may be specific to Nest or Angular, the thing you're asking about is fundamental to OOP and typed languages. I don't think it should be narrowed down to particular framework. I'd suggest to start with learning TS, which is JS with type safety. The question doesn't have anything to do with JS because there are no types or interfaces in JS.

Comment: May be I was not clear on my question. I know how TS works and how Angular works. I am trying to find some real world use cases where developers use interfaces in typescript for web development.

Comment: Interfaces are used to specify types. There's nothing special in using them for web development or any other field. It's like asking about how to use variables in desktop applications. They just exist and can be used wherever they are needed.  Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean, especially since you're already familiar with TS, Angular and DI concepts. Interface is fundamental OOP concept that doesn't depend on the context where it's used. The only special thing about TS interfaces is that they provide structural compatibility https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

Comment: As for me, switching to TS for server side was a good thing because this allows to eliminate some human mistakes and spare less time on checking docs if a method I'm using exists and has expected signature - it's already listed in IDE and causes compilation error when used incorrectly. If a developer deals with response object, it's typed as `res: Response`, only expected properties can be accessed this way.

Comment: Agree with @estus, I use Interfaces just as I used to do with Java or C#. Sometimes as simple types, sometimes as Contracts.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your confusion comes from the fact that Entities, DTO's, and interfaces all exist as options in Nest.

I have not encountered a case where it would be preferable to user interfaces instead of DTO's.

If you're coming from Angular, you can think about using DTO's like Angular uses interfaces.